# Difference between GPIOx_BSSR and GPIOx_BRR on STM32F1xx?

Tags: arm, stm32, gpio

I'm reading the [reference manual of the STM32F1xx family](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf).

page 173 & 174 describe the BSSR and BRR registers of the GPIO peripheral.

I don't understand the difference between the reset part of the BSSR register and the BRR register. They both reset the bits set to 1 and left the others untouched, right ? What's the purpose of BRR then ?

[image: BSSR documentation]

[image: BRR documentation]

Comment: If you have some 16bit mask, then you can write the low 16bits to BSRR; take a complement and write it to BRR.  You don't have to do any shifting.  It probably maps to the same logic (flip-flop/whatever), so BSRR(16..32) is the same as BRR(0..15) but no need to shift things.  Both are atomic safe as they are one to write.  If you are not managing a bank (like power sleep/restore), then the one register only makes sense.  However, you might want to manage all the pins at once.

Comment: Ok, sounds complicated to save a shift, but kind of makes sense. Thanks !